# How to get anonymous list of live streams by game

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api

I run the LiveStreamBrowser family of Chrome extensions, which display listings of currently live streams for popular games. I'd like to include YouTube Gaming as a provider, but I can't find a way in the API to do so.

[liveBroadcasts/list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list) and [liveStreams/list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams/list) both seem like they'd have the information I need, but neither seems to be returning anything when I use the test on the API page. liveStreams/list also complains about a missing filter parameter, when there's not one documented.

Further, I need an API that is callable directly from JavaScript. For example, Twitch's /streams API, which is called with a 'game' parameter and an API key.

Am I just missing something in the API documentation?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an API exposed for gaming live streams specifically.  You can use the [Search/list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint of the regular YouTube v3 API and filter the results return live content.  From there, you could break down the results even more, searching by the game title.

`part -> snippet`

`eventType -> live`

`type -> video` (required when setting `eventType` to `live`)

```
HTTP GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&eventType=live&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```